# Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND when sending http request

Tags: https, aws-lambda

i'm trying to call api-gateway from my lambda function using http get request,
and getting this error : getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND.

my code:

```
   exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  var https = require('http');
  var path = '/prod/updatevote';
  var options = {
      host: <my_method_stage_url>,
      path: '/prod/updatevote',
      headers: {'api-key': <my_api-key>},
      method: 'GET'
    };
  var reqPost = https.request(options, function(res) {
        console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {

        });
        context.succeed('Blah');
    });

    console.log('yes');
};
```

can someone help me please..?

thanks,
Hanan

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have public access to the URL you are hitting.Connecting/Configuring  to your organizations VPC, subnet and security groups will help you to connect.